# Java Applet Text highlights on rollover

Tags: java, swing, text, highlight, japplet

I'm trying to figure out how to make non-editable text (not a JTextField) whose background color changes when the mouse rolls over it. I tried using JButton implementing ActionListener and hiding elements to make the button appear to be just text, but it only allows me to change icons on rollover and detect when the button is clicked. Another thought was to use MouseListener and declare the specific coordinates of a rectangle around the text, where upon mouseMoved it could initiate the highlight. But w/ that there's a problem for varying string lengths and word wrap etc. What is the best object, and listener combo to achieve the effect of a highlighted text field on mouse rollover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm maybe use a foucs listener and when the field gains foucs select all the text?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TextField extends JTextField {


public TextField(String text) {
    super(text);

    addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
             selectAll();
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JTextField tf = new JTextField("normal field");
            f.add(tf, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            TextField ftf =
                    new TextField("funny text field");
            f.add(ftf, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            f.pack();
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

EDIT:

Hmmm actually found an even better way with the above method you'd have to click on the textfield to gain focus, now i've used a thread to check when the mouse is over the components co-ordinates and then to highlight the field, I used a boolean to control the highlighting as constant highlighting throws an error. Hope this is what you want:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TextFieldHighlight extends JTextField {

    static JTextField ftf;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


                ftf = new JTextField("Highlight");
                ftf.setEditable(false);
                f.add(ftf, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
                Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    boolean focused = false;

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        while (true) {
                            if (mouseIsOverDisplayPanel()) {
                                if (ftf.hasFocus() && focused == false) {
                                    ftf.selectAll();
                                    focused = true;
                                } else if (!ftf.hasFocus()) {
                                    focused = false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                thread.start();
            }
        });

    }

    private static boolean mouseIsOverDisplayPanel() {

        if (MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x >= ftf.getLocationOnScreen().x
                && MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x <= ftf.getLocationOnScreen().x + ftf.getWidth()
                && MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y >= ftf.getLocationOnScreen().y
                && MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y <= ftf.getLocationOnScreen().y + ftf.getHeight()) {

            return true;

        } else {

            return false;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try it out and let you know

Comment: thank you! I think this 2nd example can be turned into what I want. I just need to try and make it smoother and make it OO. but still kinda requires that I pass it the rectangular coordinates of the textfield.

Comment: Hmm i'm sure though then you could just add a few parameters to the mouseIsOverDisplayPanel() which will accept the rectangle co-ords rather then calculating them in the mouseIsOverDisplayPanel() method?

Comment: yes but then it becomes an equivalent solution to using mouse listener to hover over a rectangle: http://www.realapplets.com/tutorial/MouseClickExample.html although i do like your thought on using selectAll for text highlighting rather than changing the background as in other objects

Comment: Not really, mouse listener waits for an even like a click or something to activate where as this checks the co-ords of the mouse until they enter the text fields bounds? And thanks :)

Comment: MouseListener has an event listener for movement events as well: public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) which behind the scenes is the same as having a thread checking where the mouse is.

Comment: whoops i sent u the wrong example sorry. but there is a mouseMoved method in mouselistener.

Comment: MouseMotionListener: www.realapplets.com/tutorial/MouseMotionExample.html

Comment: Yes, they do have the same logic, but either code is usable and even interchangeable. I am confused though as too what's wrong with it " becoming an equivalent solution to using mouse listener "?

Comment: nothing is wrong with it :) just more code. and btw as for the rectangle business i believe that I can use textfield.contains(point) to check whether the mouse is within the rectangle rather than using greater than and less than signs - which will make it look pretty clean. thanks for ur help so far.